# Setting an Array inside a prepared SQL statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, prepared-statement

I was told that "There is no way to bind an array to an SQL statement using prepared statements" but I have done it. I am having trouble recreating it though.

I have a statement that updates the database:

```
if (isset($_POST['printRow'])){
$ids = "";
foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $rowid)
{
        if(!empty($ids)) $ids .= ',';
        $ids .= $rowid;
        $_SESSION['ids'] = $ids;
}
}
```

Here I forgot to post the WORKING code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE just_ink SET deleted=1 WHERE ID IN( " . $ids . ")");
    $stmt->execute();
```

But I still have the following problem:

Where $ids can be either one or multiple ids.

So here is the problem, if I try to take $ids and set a SESSION with it

```
($_SESSION['ids'] = $ids;)
```

For use on another page.

On the next page I want to select data using $_SESSION['ids'] so,

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM just_ink WHERE ID IN( " . $_SESSION['ids'] . ")");
$stmt->execute();
```

But this doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: That is not a prepared statement

Comment: @Jens it was prepared by php :) ( I know, I know )

Comment: You don't quote ids. Moreover, you don't protect anything. The interest of prepared statements is that they protect the data you insert in your database. Which is absolutely not your case here.

Comment: Just because you call `prepare()`, doesn't make it a prepared statement if you're injecting values directly into the SQL query: use placeholders, prepare it properly, and bind the values

Comment: Also: to concatenate all items of an array, there is a wonderful function for that: it's called [`implode`](http://php.net/implode)

Comment: I don't think a comma delimited string is the same thing as an array.  And I'm quite sure that this statement is not prepared.  And there is nothing safe or secure about it.

Comment: What is the error message you get when `this doesn't work` ?

Comment: Probably something like `column XXX does not exist`, where XXX is an id.

Comment: Do you use mysqli or PDO?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because, as you correctly said, you can't bind an array to an SQL statement using prepared statements.

The correct way to bind an array is to create a string of placeholders (question marks) and then bind params in a loop.

Let's say you have an array of necessary `ID`'s called `$checkboxes`. First, we need to create a string that we will use in our query to bind required params. If `$checkboxes` has 3 items, our string will look like

```
$placeholder = "?,?,?";
```

For this we can use [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) function to create a string, where every but last element will add `?,` part to placeholder. For last element we need to concatenate single question mark.

```
$placeholder = str_repeat('?,', count($checkboxes)-1).'?';
```

Now we need to form and prepare a query that will contain our placeholders:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM just_ink WHERE ID IN (".$placeholder.")';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
```

To bind every `ID` to its placeholder we use [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) method in a loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($checkboxes); $i++) {
    $stmt->bindParam($i+1, ($checkboxes[$i]); #position is 1-indexed
}
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: @Downvoter, looking for you comment to point out where I am wrong.

Comment: Downvote does not mean an answer is wrong, just it's not a **good** answer.

Comment: @lolbas I will have no way of knowing how many IDS the admin has chosen. I have updated my original post with code that works.

Comment: @Justin using `count` function you don't need to know `ID`'s count. As for your "code that works" - indeed, it might do what you want it to, but you just mess up the purpose of using prepared statements - you are vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays with mysqli prepared statements by using call_user_func_array

Your code would end up something like this

```
$varArray = array();
$questionArray = array();
foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $daNumber=>$daValue) {
    $questionArray[] = "?";

    //We're declaring these as strings, if they were ints, they would be i
    $varArray[0] .= 's';

    //These must be relational variables. The ampersand is vry important.
    $varArray[] = &$_POST['checkbox'][$daNumber];
}

//comma separated series of questionmarks    
$allDaQuestions = implode(', ', $questionArray);


$query = "SELECT * FROM just_ink WHERE ID IN ($allDaQuestions)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

//Where the magic happens
call_user_func_array(array(&$stmt, 'bind_param'), $varArray);

//continue with your regularly scheduled broadcast
$stmt->execute();
//etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

did you set session_start() at the beginning of the file? you can't use $_SESSION if you don't do that first

Comment: Not related to session.

Comment: uh? so why is the script has a $_SESSION in the query if it's not related?

Comment: The problem is not related to session. I already gave the answer in the comments: there is no quote around each id, so mysql will try to interpret each id as a column name.

Comment: @Arcesilas the problem is not in quoting `ID`'s. I am using similar query along with method described in my answer and it doesn't try to interpret each ID as a column name.

Comment: We don't know how are OP's ids. And OP seem to have disappear.

Comment: Yes I do have session started on each page. I though that was implied sorry.

Comment: @Arcesilas sorry for the delay, i had a serious of phone calls for work.